# How to define `sc_fixed` variables that have word/integer lengths that are based off (but not the same size as!) those of a template parameter

Tags: systemc

Let's say I want to write a generic SystemC module which does some algorithm processing on fixed point data of various representations, so I implement it as as module template where the fixed point input/output type is specified as a template parameter. My algorithm requires more headroom for it's intermediate operations than is available by the input/output type so I'd like to declare some intermediate fixed point variables which have more integer bits but the same number of fractional bits. How do I do this? Is there any way to query the word/integer lengths of the `sc_fixed` template parameter and use/modify them to define new `sc_fixed` variables within the module.

I've tried using the `wl()` and `iwl()` methods but these only get evaluated at runtime so can't be used as template arguments.

Here is an example of what doesn't work:

```
template <typename T>
SC_MODULE(proc)
{
    sc_in<bool> clk;    // Clock signal
    sc_in<bool> rst_n;  // Reset signal
    sc_in<T> in_sig;    // Input signal
    sc_out<T> out_sig;  // Output signal

    const T tttt;
    typedef sc_fixed<tttt.wl()+3, tttt.iwl()+3> internal_sig_t;
    internal_sig_t internal_sig_0, internal_sig_1;

    ...
}
```

Is there a way of doing this which actually works?

Note: As a workaround I could just pass the `sc_fixed` template parameters instead of the predefined type but this starts getting very messy if I have multiple input/output types with different options for not just for word/integer lengths so would prefer not to go this route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided on this forum thread: https://forums.accellera.org/topic/7596-how-to-define-sc_fixed-variables-that-have-wordinteger-lengths-that-are-based-off-but-not-the-same-size-as-those-of-a-template-parameter/